# what's the purpose and meaning of e in jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In the following code, there are two 'e's, are they about the same object/type or actually about different things?

```
(function(e) {
  var t = {
    init: function() {
      e(".pic").length && this.show()
    }
  };
  window.Booth = t;
})(jQuery);
```

Also, I am a little confused with the overall semantics of the code snippet above, any documentation out there can explain it?

Comment: There is no purpose, really. It's an abbreviation of 'event', and is used to refer to the local function.

Comment: @JackWilliams Pay a-bloody-ttention, all right?

Comment: Can anyone please remove the duplicate link? This is really not a duplicate. My rating got moved down 2 points because of the wrong judgement. I did see the Q earlier and realized that it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have is an [anonymous, self-executing function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).

the function is passed the jquery object (which is a function).  `e(".pic")` is the same as `$(".pic")` or `jQuery(".pic")` because e is just a reference to jQuery.

Comment: Ok, so the first e is an object - most of times an event object; and the 2nd e is an abbreviation of jQuery or $. very nice! Thanks!

Comment: there's no event, ignore Jack William's comment.  the function has one argument, "e" and it's being passed "jQuery" (last line of code).

Answer (score 5):

In this case, it's an alias for `jQuery`. Usually people use `$`, but in this case they didn't.